# VBA Excel Merging Several Different Structure Sheets Using Common Combined Sheet Headers

Tags: excel, vba

I have several sheets with different structure that i need to merge using some of the columns headers that are common 
I gathered in the one sheet ("Combine") the common headers and tried to write a macro to find the same column and to its data to the combine sheet, the macro is only getting the first column and not proceeding.

Any guidance with this issue will be appreciated

```
Dim II%, XX%, ZZ%, I% ' Dim as long

Dim Sht As Worksheet  ' Every Sheet on This Workbook
Dim Comb As Worksheet ' Combine Sheet

Set Comb = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Combine")

II = 2 ' Start on row 2 - Sheet1 & Sheet2
XX = 2 ' Start on row 2 - Combine sheet

'Looping through the worksheets in the workbook
For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ' ignore Sheet "Combine" and "Val"
    If Sht.Name <> "Combine" And Sht.Name <> "Val" Then

    For ZZ = 1 To 100
        For I = 1 To 100
            If Sheets(Sht.Name).Cells(1, I).Value = Comb.Cells(1, ZZ).Value Then

            Do Until IsEmpty(Sht.Columns(1).Cells(II))
            Comb.Cells(XX, ZZ).Value = Sheets(Sht.Name).Cells(II, I).Value
            II = II + 1
            XX = XX + 1
            Loop

            End If
        Next I
    I = 1

    Next ZZ

    End If
    II = 2 ' Reset 1st Loop to capture the new sheet data

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have multiple sheets that have a heading row of some number of columns.  You then have data rows below this in corresponding columns.

You’ve looked at the headings in each sheet and added those names that are common to a sheet you’ve called Combine.  Not all columns on all sheets are found on the Combine sheet.  The Combine sheet is a subset of the total column names in the workbook.

The sheets might contain data from several test runs or whatever.  The output might contain common columns as well as some additional data. For example, sheet 1 could contain date, time, location, and result.  Sheet 2 could contain date, time, and tester.

You want a combined sheet that shows the common fields, in this case Date, Time, Result, and Tester.  You’ve already determined the common headings.

I think your problem might be in `Do Until IsEmpty(Sht.Columns(1).Cells(II))`.  You may be encountering an empty cell.

Also, it is much faster to use Excel's built-in functions to perform moving large blocks of data between sheets.

Given you seem to be learning about VBA and have made a pretty good attempt, I took the liberty to provide you with an example that uses a more advanced way for solving the problem

The code below in effect concatenates the data from each sheet and common column on to the Combine sheet.  It leaves blanks where a column does not have a data sheet have data that would be copied into the Combine column.  This means that there will be blank cells under the columns Result and Test – based on the source data sheet.

I hope you find this helpful and that it answers your question.  I have learned a lot from other's example on this site and am trying to pay it forward.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Tester()
    'Not needed
    'Dim II%, XX%, ZZ%, I% ' Dim as long

    Dim Comb As Worksheet ' Combine Sheet
    Set Comb = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Combine")

    'Declare a range object and assign it to contain column names
    'from Combine.  This range, converted to a list
    'below will compare the combined heading names with
    'each column heading on each sheet.
    Dim rngCombineHeadings As Range
    'set combine headings into the range using the function
    'EndOfRangeColumn, which is decribed below
    Set rngCombineHeadings = EndOfRangeColumn(Comb.Range("A1"))

    'Declare a collection to be used in the for loop to compare
    'Combine column headings with each source sheets headings
    'Only copy those columns that match
    Dim colCombinedHeadings As Collection
    'Get a collection (aka list of strings) of the column headings
    Set colCombinedHeadings = GetCommonHeadings(rngCombineHeadings)

    'Declare two ranges to be used as the index inside
    'for loops below.
    Dim combineColTargetRng As Range
    Dim colRng As Range

    'Declare a variant to used use the index for looing
    'through the Combine sheet headings
    Dim vHeading As Variant

    'Declare tblRng.  It will be set to contain the entire data table
    'on each sheet.  Row 1 contains the headings, rows 2 - n contain
    'the data that may be moved.
    Dim tblRng As Range

    'This is the range that will be manipulated and copied
    'to the Combine sheet
    Dim copyRng As Range

    'Looping through the worksheets in the workbook
    'Index variable used in for each loop below best practice is
    'declare you variables near where they are used.
    Dim Sht As Worksheet  ' Every Sheet on This Workbook
    For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        ' ignore Sheet "Combine" and "Val"
        If Sht.Name <> "Combine" And Sht.Name <> "Val" Then

            'Set the data table to the tblRng object.
            Set tblRng = EndOfRangeRow(Sht.Range("A1"))
            Set tblRng = EndOfRangeColumn(tblRng)

            'For each sheet, loop through each headings on
            'the Combined sheet and compare those to the
            'headings on the data table on the current sheet
            For Each vHeading In colCombinedHeadings
                For Each colRng In tblRng.Columns

                    'if the heading on Combined = the current
                    'columns heading then, copy the data
                    'to the combined sheet.
                    If vHeading = colRng.Value2(1, 1) Then

                        'Resize the copy range to exclude the heading row
                        'and to reduce the size by one row, reflecting removal
                        'of the header row from the range
                        Set copyRng = ResizeTheRange(colRng.Offset(1, 0))

                        'Find the column on the Combine sheet that
                        'matches the current value in vHeading
                        Set combineColTargetRng = rngCombineHeadings.Find(colRng.Value2(1, 1))

                        'Copy the current sheet-current column to the clipboard
                        copyRng.Copy

                        'The if statement below determines if this is the first
                        'column of data being copied to the Combine sheet
                        'if it is, the row 2 current column is empty
                        'otherwise it has a value and we need to move the paste point
                        'to the end of the current Combine sheet column
                        If combineColTargetRng.Offset(1, 0).Value2 = "" Then
                            Set combineColTargetRng = combineColTargetRng.Offset(1, 0)
                        Else
                            Set combineColTargetRng = EndOfRangeRow(combineColTargetRng)
                            Set combineColTargetRng = _
                                combineColTargetRng.Offset( _
                                     combineColTargetRng.Rows.Count, 0)
                        End If

                        'Paste the values copied from the current sheet
                        'that are under the same column heading as on the combined sheet
                        'There are a number of options for pasteSpecial
                        'See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial
                        combineColTargetRng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub

'*****************************************************************************
'**
'**  This function demonstrates use of the ParamArray.  It enables the
'**  calling routine, to provide the range as an Excel Range, a Collection
'**  an Array, or a list of strings.
'**
'** Calling the Function:
'**     Dim aCol as Collection
'**     Set aCol = GetCommonHeadings(aCol)
'**     Dim rngExcelRange as Range
'**     set rngExcelRange = Range("A1:X1")
'**     Set aCol = GetCommonHeadings(rngExcelRange)
'**     Dim vArr() as Variant
'**     vArr = Array("H1", "H2", "H3", "H4")
'**     Set aCol = GetCommonHeadings(vArr)
'**     Set aCol = GetCommonHeadings("Title1", "Title2", "Title3", "Title4")
Public Function GetCommonHeadings(ParamArray mRange() As Variant) As Collection
    'Instantiate the return collection
    Dim retVal As New Collection

    Dim nDx As Long

    If UBound(mRange) < 0 Then
        'Cannot do anything without the heading range
        Set retVal = Nothing
    ElseIf TypeOf mRange(0) Is Range Then
        'Heading Range is an Excel Range
        Dim rngMaster As Range
        Dim colRng As Range
        Set rngMaster = mRange(0)
        For Each colRng In rngMaster.Columns
            retVal.Add colRng.Value2
        Next
    ElseIf TypeOf mRange(0) Is Collection Then
        'Heading Range is a collection of text strings
        Set retVal = mRange(0)
    ElseIf VarType(mRange(0)) = vbArray + vbVariant Then
        'Heading Range passed is an array of strings
        Dim varArr() As Variant
        varArr = mRange(0)
        For nDx = 0 To UBound(varArr)
            retVal.Add varArr(nDx)
        Next
    ElseIf VarType(mRange(0)) = vbString Then
        'mRange contains an array of strings
        For nDx = 0 To UBound(mRange)
            retVal.Add mRange(nDx)
        Next
    Else
        Set retVal = Nothing
    End If

    Set GetCommonHeadings = retVal
End Function

'****************************************************************************
'**
'** The Functions EndOfRangeColumn, EndOfRangeRow, StartOfRangeColumn, and
'** StartOfRangeRow take one parameter which is an Excel Range.  Based on
'** the funtions name it will return the cell that is at the other end.
'** These are just wrappers to make the code more readable.  The real work
'** is done by the Private Function GetRangeAtEnd.  The private function
'** takes an Excel Range and the direction you want to move.
Public Function EndOfRangeColumn(ByRef mStartOfRange As Range) As Range
    Set EndOfRangeColumn = GetRangeAtEnd(mStartOfRange, xlToRight)
End Function

Public Function EndOfRangeRow(ByRef mStartOfRange As Range) As Range
    Set EndOfRangeRow = GetRangeAtEnd(mStartOfRange, xlDown)
End Function
Public Function StartOfRangeColumn(ByRef mEndOfRange As Range) As Range
    Set StartOfRangeColumn = GetRangeAtEnd(mStartOfRange, xlToLeft)
End Function

Public Function StartOfRangeRow(ByRef mEndOfRange As Range) As Range
    Set StartOfRangeRow = GetRangeAtEnd(mStartOfRange, xlUp)
End Function

Private Function GetRangeAtEnd(ByRef mRange As Range, ByVal mDirection As XlDirection) As Range
    Set GetRangeAtEnd = Range(mRange, mRange.End(mDirection))
End Function

'***************************************************************
'**
'** The Private Function ResizeTheRange takes an Excel range
'** provide in the parameter.  In effect it removes the first
'** row from the provided range, and reduces the size by one.
Private Function ResizeTheRange(ByRef mRange As Range) As Range
    Dim retVal As Range
    Set retVal = mRange.Offset(1, 0)
    Set retVal = retVal.Resize(retVal.Rows.Count - 1, 1)
    Set retVal = EndOfRangeRow(retVal)
    Set ResizeTheRange = retVal
End Function
```